# Move Album with pictures to a folder in iPhone 11 / iOS 16.1

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photos.app

I just moved to iOS from Android. I backed up photos through the Move to iOS app from Android to iOS.
In the android all the 3k+ photos were organized in folders. Unfortunately now it's all in the ***recent*** album.

**How do I organize the album, photos in different albums and preferably in different folders too** ?

For some reasons the photos can't be sorted by date or locations.
I want to keep only 1 copy of the photo, so that after moving the photo from the ***recent*** album to the ***new*** album, it does not appear and does not exist in the recent album.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to think of Albums in iOS Photos, not as physical folders, but as organisational tags. The Recents album is special in that it lists photos added in order of their import, not necessarily in the order of their creation. A photo will always be in the Recents album. This is useful when adding photos from other sources other than the camera. However the Recents Album is not the primary view you have to work with.

If you use the Library tab, from the bottom control bar, you will see photos sorted by their creation dates, and you can also summarise by year, month, day, or view all continuously.

When the iPhone has had a chance to process the files you can view photos sorted by location (where they contain location data of course), and lots of other categories besides, by selecting them in the Albums tab, again in the bottom control bar.

As to your previous folder structure, it is unfortunate that that has not been translated as you migrated. Unfortunately I can't advise on why that happened, having never migrated from Android. You may have to recreate your  previous folder structure as Albums in Photos.

Note, as I said earlier that Albums are more of an organisational tag, a photo can be added to more than one Album at a time. This is useful if a photo merits being in more than one Album at a time, say holiday snaps & dogs you saw on holiday, but note, it **does not** duplicate the photo, you do not waste space by doing so.

Some time spent familiarising yourself with the interface will present all these things to you in time. Be sure to read the [iOS User Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/welcome/ios).

Comment: Thnx for the ans. Is it possible to add an image to an album and remove the same from the recent album ?

Comment: No. You can add an image to another Album, but that image will always appear in Recents, as I stated in the answer. It is just a view of all images sorted by import date. It doesn't have to be used as the primary way of viewing images. Your images are also in the Library view. Likewise that is a view of all images sorted by capture date.